# rotation on android studio

Tags: android

this is my code to rotate imageview by two buttons:

```
 btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
 reverseBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
 eagleview = (ImageView) findViewById(imageView3);

 final Matrix mat = new Matrix();
 final Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.mipmap.eagle);

   Timer timer = new Timer();


        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {


                    if (reverseBtn.isPressed()) {


                        angle= (float) (angle-1);


                        Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap,0 ,0,bMap.getWidth(),bMap.getHeight(), mat, true);

                        mat.setRotate(angle);
                        eagleview.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);



                    }

                    if (btn.isPressed()) {

                        angle= (float) (angle+1);

                        Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0,bMap.getWidth(),bMap.getHeight(), mat, true);
                        mat.setRotate(angle);
                        eagleview.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);


                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }, 0, 5);
```

this code rotate the image, but there is one problem: while the image is rotating the image is also come front and back( its like its become larger and then smaller). where is my mistake? thanks

Comment: How about you actually rotate the image view using `imageView.setRotation(float)`?

Comment: its work. so simple. thanks.